# How can I fix sorting in angularjs select box and set selected item?

Tags: c#, angularjs

I'm trying to make angularjs select box with the list of months.

I pass the list of month names from server (I use C#)

First I tried passing months like a dictionary:

```
var months = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
  {1, Strings.January}, {2, Strings.February}, {3, Strings.March}, 
  {4, Strings.April}, {5, Strings.May}, {6, Strings.June}, 
  {7, Strings.July}, {8, Strings.August}, {9, Strings.September}, 
  {10, Strings.October}, {11, Strings.November}, {12, Strings.December}
};
```

And my select looked like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="period.StartMonth" ng-options="value for (key, value) in model.Months track by key">
</select>
```

In this case select gets populated with months, BUT! I have 2 problems here and I suspect that they are related:

1. My list of months has wrong sorting. It is sorted by the key *as though the key was a string, not an integer*. First I get January, then October, November etc.
2. No value gets selected. I specified "track by key", but obviously as it assumes that the key is string, it ignores integer value stored in period.StartMonth. When I tried to set "track by value" and set ng-model="period.StartMonthName", the value was selected ok. But that is not the way I'd like it to have.

I also tried to pass months as List but I still get wrong sorting.

Any ideas how I can explain to angularjs that my key is integer and fix sorting/setting selected item?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

Create your months in this format.

```
$scope.months = [{id:1, name :"January"},{id:2, name :"February"},
                {id:3, name :"March"},{id:4, name :"April"},
                {id:5, name :"May"},{id:6, name :"June"},
                {id:7, name :"July"},{id:8, name :"August"},
                {id:9, name :"September"},{id:10, name :"October"},
                {id:11, name :"November"},{id:12, name :"December"}];
```

And in your html

```
   <select id="month" name="month" ng-model="period.StartMonth" 
         ng-options="month.id as month.name for month in months"></select>

     selected month id = {{period.StartMonth}}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But anyway, I wonder if it's possible somehow to use Dictionary passed from server. Seems strange that angular takes integer keys for strings and breaks correct sorting.

Comment: I don't think the Dictionary is ordered by its implementation. If that is correct you cannot expect the months will be listed as you wanted.

Comment: At least angular could do no sorting when it was not asked for it =)

Answer (score 0):

try to add trailing zeros for your keys.

sorting:

```
var months = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        {01, Strings.January}, {02, Strings.February}, {03, Strings.March}, 
        {04, Strings.April}, {05, Strings.May}, {06, Strings.June}, 
        {07, Strings.July}, {08, Strings.August}, {09, Strings.September}, 
        {10, Strings.October}, {11, Strings.November}, {12, Strings.December}
    };
```

selecting
2. when you select the month, either pass the whole object like: {01, "January"} and set ng-model="period.StartMonth.id" or make period.StartMonth equal to the id ( 01 ) of the selected object. In one word, ng-model's value has to match one the id's from the list you've provided to the ng-options.

Comment: then as Matthews suggested, go with an array of objects instead of your  Dictionary. That will help.